# In-game save feature (in tkinter game)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a text-based game in Python using Tkinter. All the time the window contains a Label and a few Buttons (mostly 3). If it didn't have GUI, I could just use Pickle or even Python i/o (.txt file) to save data and later retrieve it.  But what is the best way to tell the program to load the exact widgets without losing bindings, buttons' commands, classes etc.?  P.S.: Buttons lead to cleaning the frame of widgets and summoning new widgets. I'm thinking of assigning a lambda (button's command) to a variable and then saving it (Pickle?) to be able to load it in the future and get the right point in the plot. Should I go for it or is there a better, alternative way to accomplish the thing? (If using lambda may work, I'd still be grateful to see your way of doing that.)

Comment: Why can't you save the data to a file and have an option to reload an existing game? What is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: Read here for different types of configuration file formats and which ones you should use: https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/

Comment: Are you still working on this project? I have a project that will allow you to do just this kind of thing using JSON as *markup*. You can load new JSON on the fly, dynamically changing the views. It's still in early stages but includes data- and command-binding: https://github.com/badkraft/razorware.pixelbox

Answer (score 1):

You need to save stuff in some kind of config file. In generel I'd recommend JSON and YAML as file formats also ini for ease of parsing.

Also, do not forget about the windows registry (portability lost then though).

Comment: I would not recommend YAML at all. Too complicated and messy to use. I would much rather use JSON, `ConfigParser` or a `.py` file

Answer (score 1):

My understanding was that you need a widget manager, to put them where you want and it is easy to pick up values.

Create a new class called Manager, make two functions, _setNewWidget, _deleteWidget, like this:

```
class Manager():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        objects = {}

    def _createButton(self, frame, id, function, etc):
        # object[id] = frame.Button(function, etc, ...) i dnt' know sintaxes, but this is the way

    def _deleteWidget(self, id):
        # object[id] = None or del(object[id]) same here
```

To get, just:

```
manager = Manager()
manager._createWidget("button_fase_one", frameTk, etc, etc)
manager.objects["button_fase_one"].changeFrame() # example
print(manager.objects["button_fase_one"].text)
```

In this way u can create objects and blit where u want.

To save data just make another function and save as json.